# selecting top record in ORACLE join statement between subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to ask for your help for constructing a single ORACLE SQL statement:

using job table as below

```
Object | Operation | Time  
A      | Move      | 12:01  
B      | Move      | 12:02  
C      | Pickup    | 12:03  
D      | Move      | 12:04  
B      | Pickup    | 12:05
```

to get the result table as below.

```
Object | Operation | Time  | Cause  
A      | Move      | 12:01 | C  
B      | Move      | 12:02 | C  
D      | Move      | 12:04 | B
```

This is to figure out which Pickup operation caused each Move operation.
"Cause" column must include Object of the pickup job record with smallest time right next to move operation.

I have some ideas as below but do not know how to.
-. It requires join statement between subquery for Move and subquery for Pickup
-. Subquery for Pickup must be partitioned by move record to be joined
-. Must select top record only from each partition of Pickup subquery

Comment: won't `minimum(colName)` solve your 3rd requirement? Good luck.

Comment: Data type of column 'Time'?

Comment: @shellter must be MIN() per every Move record

Comment: @techdo it's in DATE although I wrote HH:MM only in the example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my try:

```
select  m.object, m.operation, m.time, 
  max(p.object) keep (dense_rank first order by p.time) cause,
  max(p.time) keep (dense_rank first order by p.time) cause_time
from a m
join a p on (p.time > m.time)
where m.operation = 'Move'
and p.operation = 'Pickup'
group by m.object, m.operation, m.time;
```

see [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56c84/4)

I've put column time as number, this does not have any importance as it is sortable.

I've splitted the table in two, Moves and Pickups and the join is made on time, time of `pickup` being greater than time of `move`. (This type of join is not great on performance). Then I `choose` the pickup with smallest `time`(`first` clause, with `order by p.time`).

Comment: Thank you for not only SQL statement but also kind explanations :)

Answer (score 4):

This is my try:

```
select object, operation, time, t.pobject
from a join 
   (select object pobject, time cur, lag(time,1, 0) over (order by time  ) prev 
      from a
     where operation = 'Pickup')t 
on a.time > t.prev and a.time <= t.cur
where operation = 'Move';
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56c84/55)

Comment: +1, but I still need more study to understand how it works :)

Comment: @ShonerSul, Explanation: the inner select takes only lines of 'Pickup' and uses `lag` function to get the time of previous record (so basically now I have the start time and end time of all 'Move's). Then I can join it with all 'Move' records

Answer (score 4):

There is one from old-school

```
select j1.Object, j1.Operation, j1.Time, substr(min(j2.Time || j2.Object), 6) Cause
from job j1, job j2
where j1.Operation like 'Move'
  and j1.Time < j2.Time
  and j2.Operation like 'Pickup'
group by j1.Object, j1.Operation, j1.Time
```

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5b2fe/1/0)

Comment: like this one, without using fancy "platform-specific" functions. Can someone do it using pure SQL?

Comment: @cha It's quite pure :) Replace substr() with substring() and you will get the ANSI SQL solution.

Comment: Although I accepted another answer since it can include other columns of Pickup record, personally I prefer this one for its simplicity :)

Comment: @Shoner Sul This one can include any column too ;) substr(min(j2.Time || j2.Operation), substr(min(j2.Time || j2.Time), substr(min(j2.Time || j2.Cause) :)